# How to identify where my python script is slow running

Tags: python, optimization, runtime

I am returning to a functional python script with the intent of optimizing the runtime. For the most part, I have been using timeit and tqmd to track how long individual functions take to run, but is there a way to run a single function and track the performance of all the commands in the python script to get a single output?

For example:

```
def funct_a(a):
    print(a)
def funct_b(b):
    complex_function(a)
def funct_c(c):
    return c -5

funct_a(5)
funct_b(Oregon)
funct_c(873)
```

Ideally i would like to see some output of a performance check that reads like this:

```
funct_a runtime:.000000001 ms
funct_b runtime: 59 ms
funct_c runtime: .00000002 ms
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) is made for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a profiler.

I like to use a default profiler (Already included in python) called cProfile.

You can then visualise the data using snakeviz.

This is a rough way on how to use it:

```
import cProfile
import pstats

with cProfile.Profile() as pr:
    {CODE OR FUNCTION HERE}

stats = pstats.Stats(pr)
stats.sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.TIME)
# Now you have two options, either print the data or save it as a file
stats.print_stats() # Print The Stats
stats.dump_stats("File/path.prof") # Saves the data in a file, can me used to see the data visually
```

Now to visualise it:

1. Install snakeviz
2. Go to your filepath
3. Open cmd/terminal and type `snakeviz filename.prof`

For further clarification, watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_a0fN48Alw&t=188s&ab_channel=mCoding

Comment: Oh this is exactly what I was after! Thank you, I will dive into this

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

start = time.time()
#code goes here
end = time.time()
print('Time for code to run: ', end - start)
```

Comment: Yes, I have applied this to the individual functions in the script to see just that one runtime at a time. I wanted to see if there was something that could tell me all the runtimes for all the functions at once

Comment: You can use it for each individual function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module:

```
import timeit

def funct_a(a):
    return a

def funct_b(b):
    return [b]*20
    
def funct_c(c):
    return c-5

>>> print(timeit.timeit('funct_a(5)', globals=globals()))
0.09223939990624785

>>> print(timeit.timeit('funct_b("Oregon")', globals=globals()))
0.260303599992767

>>> print(timeit.timeit('funct_c(873)', globals=globals()))
0.14657660003285855
```